# Driver installation on Lenovo laptop

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers, lenovo-laptop

I recently installed Windows 8.1 (32 bit) on my Lenovo G580 laptop. I downloaded all the drivers from http://support.lenovo.com/us but some of the drivers are not getting installed, such as Intel power management, Realtek audio driver, etc. How can I fix this?

I also installed the Synaptics touchpad driver (only to enable scroll). The driver got installed, but the scroll is still not working. Any fix for this?

Comment: Try lenovo System Update software. This should find and install most recent drivers for you computer and system. I had problems with Win 8.1 on my Lenovo T400 in general but I have really old laptop which does not have support from Lenovo for any OS except Win7 yet. I think this is not your case. So again, I just suggest Lenovo System Update software.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the touchpad might happen due to incompatibility issues for the touchpad driver. If you have not installed the latest driver for Windows 8.1, you might find such scenarios while using the touchpad.

If they are not for Windows 8.1, then, install the latest available driver in Windows compatibility and see if it works.

Follow the methods:

**Method 1:**

Follow the steps to update the driver using the previous version of drivers for the touchpad:

1. Press Windows and X key together and select Device Manager.
2. Locate the Mice and other pointing devices/Touchpad device icon. Right click on the driver icon.
3. Select Update driver software.
4. Select “Browse my computer for a driver software”.
5. Select “Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer”.
6. Select the Touchpad driver from the list of the drivers according your device model and installed.
7. If this does not work, follow the steps from ‘a’ to ‘c’ and select “Search automatically for the updated driver”.

Check if this fixes the issue. If not, proceed to the next method.

**Method 2:**

Refer to the link and enter the name of the laptop inside the search box to find the latest available drivers for the laptop:

http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-g-series-laptops/lenovo-g580-notebook

If you have latest drivers for Windows 8.1, you can download the latest versions, uninstall the current versions and then install the latest versions. Otherwise, download the latest drivers and proceed further.

If they are not available for Windows 8.1, follow the steps

**Note:** Before uninstalling the touchpad driver currently installed, please make sure that you have downloaded the latest driver for the touchpad device.

1. Press Windows and X key on your desktop and click on Device Manager.
2. Expand ‘Mouse and other pointing device’.
3. Locate the Touchpad driver.
4. Right-click on the driver icon and click on Uninstall.
5. Locate the folder which contains the setup file for the latest driver that you have downloaded.
6. Right click on the setup file and click on Properties.
7. Go to compatibility tab and check the box which states “Run the program in compatibility mode for”.
8. Select Windows from the drop down list.(The previous version on which the touchpad worked or the version for which the drivers are available)
9. Click on OK.
10. Follow the onscreen instruction to install the driver in compatibility mode.

[Source](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-performance/after-installing-windows-81-problems-problems-and/c955cc33-2212-4726-b349-64b18d9e6fdc)

For the other devices, follow a similar approach, substituting touchpad driver with the relevant devices (Intel Power Management, Realtek Audio etc.)